# trying to run example app in React native and npm start command is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I am new to app creating and I am learing react-native.
when I try to run my example app i am facing an issue

Command used:

```
npm start
```

Response:

```
  npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
  npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
  npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
  npm ERR!   npm run
```

when i tried to fix it:
Command:

```
npm audit fix
```

Response:

```
json5  <1.0.2
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution in JSON5 via Parse Method - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-9c47-m6qq-7p4h
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/find-babel-config/node_modules/json5
  find-babel-config  <=1.2.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of json5
  node_modules/find-babel-config
    babel-plugin-module-resolver  2.3.0 - 4.1.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of find-babel-config
    node_modules/babel-plugin-module-resolver
      babel-preset-expo  *
      Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-plugin-module-resolver
      node_modules/babel-preset-expo
        expo  >=14.0.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/cli
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/config
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/config-plugins
        Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-preset-expo
        Depends on vulnerable versions of expo-asset
        Depends on vulnerable versions of expo-constants
        node_modules/expo

xml2js  <0.5.0
Severity: moderate
xml2js is vulnerable to prototype pollution  - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-776f-qx25-q3cc
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/xml2js
  @expo/config-plugins  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of xml2js
  node_modules/@expo/config-plugins
  node_modules/expo/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins
    @expo/cli  >=0.1.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/config
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/config-plugins
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/dev-server
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/metro-config
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/prebuild-config
    node_modules/@expo/cli
    @expo/config  >=3.3.23-alpha.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/config-plugins
    node_modules/@expo/config
    node_modules/expo/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/config
      @expo/metro-config  >=0.1.49-alpha.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/config
      node_modules/@expo/metro-config
        @expo/dev-server  >=0.1.49-alpha.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/metro-config
        node_modules/@expo/dev-server
      expo-constants  >=10.1.2
      Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/config
      node_modules/expo-asset/node_modules/expo-constants
      node_modules/expo/node_modules/expo-constants
        expo-asset  >=8.6.1
        Depends on vulnerable versions of expo-constants
        node_modules/expo-asset
    @expo/prebuild-config  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/config
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/config-plugins
    Depends on vulnerable versions of xml2js
    node_modules/@expo/prebuild-config
      expo-splash-screen  >=0.14.1
      Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/prebuild-config
      node_modules/expo-splash-screen
```

I trend searching online for fix but its confusing for me.

Comment: You need to specify the scripts in your `package.json`... try running `npx expo start` instead.